# Need help proving cardinal of $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: n \le x, d|n\}= \lfloor \frac{x}{d} \rfloor$

Tags: number-theory

I need to show this
$\{n \in \mathbb{N}: n \le x, d|n\} = \lfloor {\frac{x}{d}} \rfloor$

but I don't know where to start =(

Answer (score 1):

Here is the way of doing it. Just write the elements of your set

$$\{n \in \mathbb{N}: n \le x, d|n\}=\{d,2d,3d,\dots,kd\}$$ and check that $k=\lfloor {\frac{x}{d}} \rfloor$.